# search mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Please help, Im trying to search for mysql records using an html form to display the corresponding record for the entered primary key.
Here's my html form:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search"></td>
```

And here's the new.php form action:,

```
mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT HOSPNUM FROM t2 WHERE FIRSTNAME='{$_POST["fname"]}'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   <input name="hnum" type="text" id="hospnum" value="<?php echo $row['HOSPNUM']; ?>"        />
   }
mysql_close($con);
   ?>
```

How do I get to display the hospnum in the html inputbox when I input the fname and then click the search button.

Comment: Does that actually work without an error message? Your entire `<input>` tag should be surrounded by an echo statement or assigning it to a variable. Right now you just have HTML sitting in the middle of your php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This script, as-is, is vulnerable to sql-injections. The code that follows is not dealing with this, as it's out of the scope of the original question. *Do not use this code as-is in a production environment.*

You have a small problem jumping from PHP to HTML:

```
<?php

   mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con) or die(mysql_error());
   $fname = $_POST["fname"];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT HOSPNUM FROM t2 WHERE FIRSTNAME='{$fname}'");

?>

<h3>Results:</h3>

<?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>

  <input type="text" name="hnum" value="<?php echo $row["HOSPNUM"]; ?>" />

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Also should be noted, unless they are filtering the superglobals, there is a SQL injection vulnerability.