# How to search 2 words from 2 table database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to search for 2 words in 2 tables?

For example, in an input form, I'm searching for `arrow 01`

The system will search for `arrow` in the table `film`, and `01` in the table `episode`.

Space is the separator.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however, quite impractical. You should reconsider your data structure.

Comment: What if the user searches for `house cards 01`?

Comment: hahaha, error displaying, cause just recored 1 space...
how to fix that one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264146/search-mysql-database)

Comment: You can use a search engine, ie. [Spinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?, You can split the input string using `explode($string, " ")` then create 2 SQL queries to search database. please try yourself before asking.

Comment: aha, im just a newby in php..
that why im asking first, then im searching about what u say in google..
thanks BTW..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. once the string is entered by the user, split the string based on the separator(int your case space) then store those words in array or variables. After that you can perform the process for making connection with the database as many times as the words are there or databases you need to refer